# SDWebImage on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, caching

I'm creating an image gallery where clicking on the images navigates to next view. I'm using the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library for caching images. The caching works perfectly well, and I am getting the image gallery. The problem is that if I clear the cache and run my application.

The image gets downloaded in the delegate method, but I am unable to assign the downloaded image in my button (dats in viewdidload) nor does caching happen the first time and images only gets dispayed if I run my iPad application second time (due to caching). I want the images to be downloaded and displayed when the cache is cleared. How can I do this?

I am even ready to give the entire source code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.synced = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.title=@"boom";
    jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.1040communications.net/sheeba/stepheni/iphone/stephenFlickr.json"];
    jsonData=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl];
    dict=[jsonData objectFromJSONString];
    items=[dict objectForKey:@"items"];
    story = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];
    media1= [[NSMutableArray array]retain];
    for (NSDictionary *item in items )
    {
        [story addObject:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
        [media1 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"media"]];
    }
    view1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    for(int i = 0; i < media1.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *mel=[media1 objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *escapedURL = [mel stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedURL];
        managaer=[SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

        cacheImage = [managaer imageWithURL:url1];

        //To clear the cache, uncomment these three lines
        /* SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
                     [imageCache clearDisk];
                     [imageCache clearDisk];*/
        if (cacheImage) {
            //If a cache image is present
        }
        else
        {   //If there is no cache image present, download.
            [managaer downloadWithURL:url1 delegate:self];
        }
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame =  CGRectMake(column*260+1, row*280+300, 250, 250);
        [button setImage:cacheImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"cached image:%@",cacheImage);

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i;

        [view1 addSubview:button];

        if (column == 2) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }
    }

    [view1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, (row+1) *280 + 10)];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [view1 release];
}

-(void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:  (UIImage   * )image
{
    //The image gets downloaded over here..
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload your view in `-webImageManager:didFinishWithImage:`. If you remove your subviews and reload everything in the method with your `for(int i = 0; i < media1.count; i++)` loop then your UI should update without needing to restart your app.

Comment: i tried pasting the entire for loop in webImageManager:didFinishWithImage leaving the delegate call wich is "[managaer downloadWithURL:url1 delegate:self];" in viewdidload..the -webImageManager:didFinishWithImage is not getting called ...i ll paste my entire code above..cud u help me out